# WordPress ест ОЗУ, почему?

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте!

Возникла проблема на сайте WordPress 4.7.5, также на сайте стоит компонент  WooCommerce 2.6.13

На сайт заходит 3-10 человек в сутки, но периодический возникает 500 ошибка. Обновляешь страницу - все работает. 
Поддержка хостинга указывает на такую ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 19385761 bytes) in public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1173
```

И пишет следующее:

> Данная ошибка говорит о том, что для выполнения скрипта недостаточно
>   оперативной памяти, доступной в рамках Вашего тарифного плана. На
>   Вашем текущем тарифном плане выделяется 128М на скрипт.

Я не понимаю почему так расходуется оперативная память при практически нулевой посещаемости.
Вирусов на сайте ни мной, ни поддержкой не обнаружено.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело? Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Comment: посмотрите логи, на каких страницах возникает ошибка. Мб по какому-то конкретному адресу, с него и копайте.

Comment: Голодный наверное

Comment: Любой движок сайта, ест ресурсы, если он просто работает - работает значит на него можно зайти.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте отключить все плагины кроме WooCommerce. Включить тему Storefront. Обновить все до последних версий. Получите чистую систему. Которая должна работать адекватно. Если ок, то значит где то плохой компонент - вычислить и вычистить.

Comment: У чувака сайт уже умер, не оживляй трупы, нам не нужен зомби-аппокалипсис